# No sound if Bluetooth headset set to default playback and recording

Tags: windows-10, gaming, headset, wireless-headset

I'm using a Bluetooth headset and for some reason when I set it to the default playback device as well as the default recording device (both normal and 'communication') then I don't get audio in Overwatch.

Tested:

- Have sound in Tharsis
- Have sound in VLC
- Have sound in Overwatch (windowed mode)
- No sound in Skyrim
- Have sound in Sykrim (windowed mode)
- No sound in Orcs Must Die 2
- Have sound in Orcs Must Die 2 (windowed mode)
  If I switch the default recording device to something else, then the audio does work.

I am using Windows 10.

The issue appears to be with the way games contact the audio device when in direct mode (not an expert on these things).

The headset did not come with a driver CD (appears to be built in in windows). How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have a pair of Bose QC 35s and was experiencing similar issues, usually they need to be **resolved in the settings within your specific full screen application** such as the Overwatch in-game settings.

Regarding your comment about a driver CD you do not need a manufacturer's physical copy of a driver. By the time retailers sold you the headset a CD copy of the driver would have likely been obsolete. Instead use Windows to search for drivers by clicking "update drivers" within the devices portion of your control panel.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Windows 10):

**Settings / System / Sound / Sound Control Panel / Communications / Set to "Do nothing"**